# Finding length of a loop in an integer array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist, integer

So I'm doing a code challenge where there's basically an integer array, where the value in each index points to another index. Your job is to find the length of a loop within the array, provided you start from index 0 in the array.

i.e.: numbers = {1, 3, 0, 1}; Index 0 is 1, which leads you to Index 1 which is 3, which leads to 1, which leads you back to index 1, thus creating a loop with the length of 2.

My issue is that my code is able to pass 3/5 test cases, and I am unable to find any weakness within the code that would possibly cause an error. I am not told what was expected, nor any other information other than "Test Case n Failed!"

Here is my code:

```
public static int answer(int[] numbers) {
    List<Integer> valuesUsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int nextValue, currentValue = numbers[0];
    do {
        valuesUsed.add(currentValue);
        currentValue = (nextValue = numbers[currentValue]);
    } while (!valuesUsed.contains(currentValue));
    return valuesUsed.size();
}
```

EDITS:

- Array sizes will be anywhere from 2 to 5000.
- The test cases I've received are {1, 3, 0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, in which my code passes all correctly.

Comment: perhaps you need error checking, like if the value points to an index that is out of the array. Also in the case of an empty array you should return 0;

Comment: Have added error checking. The readme I got with it said that the array would range from a size of 2, to a size of 5000. I forgot that information so I'll edit to original post.

Comment: What should be returned for {1,2,3,4,4}? I assume 1 is the answer, but got 4 from your code.

Comment: @hk6279 It should be 1. I believe I see the issue with my logic.

Comment: @hk6279 ya i think its because youre incrementing current value before its checked in the while loop.

Comment: @DanielKobe check the marked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the only error, but you forgot to add `0` to `valuesUsed`. That's the first index you encounter, so it should be added to the List prior to the loop.

EDIT:

Correction :

When you close a loop, returning `valuesUsed.size()` is wrong, since some of the encountered indices are not part of the loop.

You should return `valuesUsed.size()-valuesUsed.indexOf(currentValue)`.

For example, if the array is {1,3,1,4,2}, the loop is 1->3->4->2->1 and the length of the loop is 4 (the first element is not counted).

Comment: Hes using a do while loop so why does it matter if he adds it before?

Comment: 0 isn't contained within the loop, as there is no value of 2 in the array. The initial value that you start from is 1, as it's index 0's value, which gets added to the valuesUsed.

Comment: @Kyle What if the array is {1,0}? Isn't that a loop?

Comment: Yes, a loop with a length of two. That gets correctly calculated with the code.

Comment: @Kyle You said that your code fails for some of the inputs. You didn't say if it fail for the `{1, 3, 0, 1}` input. Does it?

Comment: It passes for the example cases that I have gotten, which are {1, 3, 0, 1}, {1, 0}, and {1, 2, 1}. (I'll add this info in the original post as well.

Comment: @Kyle It would be more helpful to know the inputs for which it fails.

Comment: That's one of the reasons I'm here, I'm not able to see the test cases. I was hoping that someone would be able to identify an error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static int answer(int[] numbers) {
    List<Integer> valuesUsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int currentValue = 0;
    int nextValue =0; 
    do {
        currentValue = nextValue;
        nextValue = numbers[currentValue];
        valuesUsed.add(nextValue );

    } while (!valuesUsed.contains(currentValue));
    return valuesUsed.size();
}
```

Comment: That isn't going to work regardless until you initialize nextValue.

Comment: i initialized nextValue and  currentValue =0

Comment: No, currentValue is initialized to 0. nextValue isn't initialized.

Comment: what this code means ,   int nextValue, currentValue = 0;

Comment: It declares an integer called nextValue, and declares another integer called currentValue and initializes only currentValue to 0.